# Google Chrome on Windows 11 - No Sound, Not in sound Mixer

Tags: windows, google-chrome, audio

I'm running Chrome (Version 123.0.6312.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) FWIW) on Win 11 Pro.

I can't get sound from any websites, my first thought was I might of turned it down one day in Windows Volume Mixer, but Chrome isn't even showing as an app in there. I don't recall ever forbiding it permissions to hardware, and can't find such an option in the settings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can other apps play? Have you checked that audio is not muted? What are your computer model and audio equipment?